# How many characters in obj-c/ios can I store in 128 kilobytes?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to store the data for my data objects in one long string. My string limit is 128k, so I was wondering just how many characters can I get into that?

Comment: 128k characters assuming normal char data type since each character is 1 byte

Answer (score 4):

Depends on encoding requirements.

• Do you really need an NSString compatible string?

• Is your data truly raw, 8 bit, data or does it have an encoding of its own?

Without answers to that, the assumption is an input of arbitrary data and an output that can be treated as a valid `NSString`.   At that point, the typical answer is to use base64 encoding, of which Google will reveal multiple NSData -> NSString solutions.

With most encoders, the size of the result can vary depending on the format of the input.  I.e. certain things encode into fewer bytes than others.   Thus "maximum" may vary depending on input format and encoding algorithm employed.